# Python 3 and Django 2 faster to load or copy object for view?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pickle

I am curious as to the most performant way to get large objects into views for Django 2

In `views.py` I need to load a large object into memory. I have this both pickled as well as a `json` file. The pickled version is only a marginal improvement at `95%` the size of the `json` version.

While I would like to do this once when the serve starts, and then have a view have access to this `module` level variable, one of my views **needs** to *modify* the object to do what it is suppose to do. So if I load it once as a `module` level variable, (here named `persistent`), we see that sequential calls use the updated variable -- as expected:

#### views.py

```
...

persistent = {'val': 0} # loaded from pickled / json file
def test(request, val):
    old = persistent['val'] # required information from unmodified object

    persistent['val'] = val # some computation which is required to modify the object
    return JsonResponse({'old': old, 'new': val})
...
```

#### urls.py

```
...
urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    path('test/<val>/', views.test, name='test')
    ,...
]
```

#### api calls

```
localhost:8000/test/10   ---> {'old': 0,    'new': 10}
localhost:8000/test/100  ---> {'old': '10', 'new': 100}
```

---

this is of course expected. However, for *my* use case, I need each call to access the original `persistent` unmodified variable.

Thus two solutions occur to me:

1. read in the object when the view is called
2. copy the persistent object when the view is called

perhaps there are even better ways to handle this.

My question is, in general, for large and possibly complex objects, what is more performant `copy.deepcopy` or reading a pickle file?

Comment: This cannot be answered for the general case: `copy` and `pickle` are based on the same protocol, but `pickle` depends *loading* a dump while `copy` depends on *creating* a dump. Objects that take long to store will be faster with `pickle`. With slow file I/O, `copy` will be faster. Objects can also special-case copying, so they may be more efficient to copy than to load. Etcetera...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thanks for the insight. I will profile it for my use-case then :). Are there any other solutions that I may not have thought of?

Comment: Seems fine. Note that if everybody reads the pickle file at the same time (startup) and it fits in the page cache, reading is probably fastest. Take note that "persistent" is a name often used for *immutable* data, so you might want to pick another name: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure